# My c# TCP Sockets program is being quarantined by Windows Defender

Tags: c#, sockets

I have written a c# program to monitor what my daughter is doing on her computer during her online lessons (due to COVID lockdown).
She has a habit of going onto Discord to chat with her friends instead of following the lesson. She also plays Minecraft during lesson time.

I don’t have the time to keep checking up on her so my wife urged me to write this software.

But the software is detected by Windows Defender as a Trojan as shown below;

*Detected: Trojan:Script/Wacatac.B!ml
This program is dangerous and executes commands from an attacker*

I can see that it is a Trojan of sorts but it is not being used in that vein. I am simply using TCP SOCKETS to allow myself or my wife to keep an eye on our daughter and to message her and if need be to close down the offending application remotely.
The way that MS Defender keeps quarantining each new compilation as I fine tune the exe to do what I need it to do is a real bind.

I am hoping that somebody might know a way around this.
After all I am using an API (System.Net.Sockets) that is part of the Microsoft DotNet library.
It is as if Microsoft were banning the use of an API that it provides.

My daughter is back at school on the 8th March 2021 so it will be redundant after that (hopefully) but as a developer I would still like to know how to solve this.

Comment: Why not just exclude the program from Windows Defender?

Comment: Why make a monitoring app at all, instead of getting something like [Circle](https://meetcircle.com), or even just configure a basic home router, to block the sites during her school hours?

Comment: While your program may not be literally the trojan fingerprinted by Defender, there's nothing in your question to suggest this is a programming question. Without a [mcve] one can't to say anything specific about the _code_, but from your description it seems like a legitimate flag from the software. It's not the use of sockets per se, but what the rest of the program does with what comes over the socket. False positives from AV software need to be taken up with the publisher of the software. If there were a _programming_ solution to your problem, then malware writers would use such solutions.

Comment: @PeterDuniho According to "What topics can I ask about here?" this qualifies as "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" and is not covered under the specific exclusions. There is no literal requirement for minimal, reproducible examples for questions of this type.

Comment: @Corey: this is not a question about _programming_ at all, nor is the reason it got closed the fact that it lacks a [mcve]. I mention that only because _in addition to being off-topic_, this question also lacks enough information for anyone to even start commenting sensibly on the code itself.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Not going to turn this into a discussion. This is a *practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development* and thus is permissible under the guidelines as given. SO is not, and has never been, solely about literal code problems.

Comment: @Corey: _"Not going to turn this into a discussion."_ -- really? could've fooled me. And you are wrong that this problem is unique to software development. It's unique to software development only in the same way that wondering what file format to use when saving your Excel spreadsheet is. Ironically, I notice that your "answer" doesn't even provide a solution. You just say "nothing you can do about it". Well, _that's_ real helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> ... close down the offending application remotely.

To some extent, this indeed makes your program "execute commands from an attacker." It seems like the issue does not lie in whatever API you use - but instead, what the program actually does.

You may try obfuscating your program with something like ConfuserEx, though it is possible that Windows Defender flags the obfuscated build as well, because this is what some real malwares do to hide themselves. The easiest solution is to place the program in a separate directory and add that directory to Windows Defender's exclude list.

Comment: Code obfuscators do tend to raise the heuristic scores on programs, making them more likely to be detected as malware. Usually the best answer is to have the program act less like malware rather than more :)

Answer (score 1):

We run up against this kind of problem frequently, and realistically there's not a lot you can do about it. False positives are just a part of what we have to deal with, and the only way to deal with them for low-distribution items like personal remote administration tools - or my own common case, custom AV upgrade scripts - is to add exceptions for your own programs when you install them on a computer, and every time you update the code.

> It is as if Microsoft were banning the use of an API that it provides.

Unfortunately malware uses those same APIs. AV vendors are constantly upgrading their definitions to catch as many threats as possible and common techniques used by malware are also present in remote administration tools.

From a quick search it looks like `Wacatac.B!ml` is a particularly problematic detection that has struck all sorts of legitimate applications, including an open-source launcher for Blender [recently](https://github.com/DotBow/Blender-Launcher) and several other items.

From experience the `!ml` tag means that the definition was derived via machine learning which means it most likely is a deep heuristic rather than a code fingerprint.

### Possible Solutions

The most general way to get around this type of heuristic detection is with [extended validation code signing](https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2018/08/16/partnering-with-the-industry-to-minimize-false-positives/). Since this requires a relatively expensive certification process it's unlikely to be a *useful* solution for your in-house child monitoring tools.

In your case perhaps a path or [file exclusion](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-exclude-files-and-folders-windows-defender-antivirus-scans) would allow you to continue to refine your tool without having to worry about it constantly being detected and blocked. I wouldn't recommend this for production systems, but for home use only it's simple, althout occasionally unreliable.

Finally, you could radically change the code. If you can't find a way to avoid detection using your current code base then consider using a different technique altogether. Enable powershell remoting and run a collector script on another machine on the network. Build a web-based agent that polls a web service (on the local network of course) to get commands to run. Use a popular library that will handle the actual communications for you rather than accessing the sockets yourself. Not as efficient maybe, but sometimes all it takes is one change to get the false positives to leave you the hell alone.